# 404 Page When I switched over to Nginx from Apache

Tags: wordpress, apache, nginx, http-status-code-404

I have Wordpress issue on my published pages... they turned into **404 Page**!

I switch from Apache to Nginx and I think this is the reason of the issue. But everything in the backend are working. Even when I edit the pages, they're just working fine. But when I publish the page, the page live permalink sends me to a 404 page.

Any idea? Any help is much appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This can b solve with the help of cPanel, Go to cPanel, in menu section select redirect and redirect all pages with 301 to your domain name like e.g `domain.com`